# Restore iPod Touch without passcode or power button

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, ipod, restore

How could I reset my 4th gen iPod Touch just using my computer and a cable? My power button doesn't work and I have the white screen of death. The only way to reset the device I've seen is to hold the power and home button and then use restore on iTunes, but I can't do that for obvious reasons.

Are there any fixes for this?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use RecBoot. Here is some information quoted from [their web site](http://jaxov.com/2010/05/recboot-iphone-recovery-mode/):

> RecBoot is a free utility for Windows and Mac users which allow you to put your iPhone / iPod Touch in recovery mode easily. Its a
>   great utility for for those iPhone users who's iPhone Home or
>   Sleep/Wake button is not fully functional. Moreover this utility saves
>   you from learning the 3-4 steps of putting your iPhone into recovery
>   mode manually. Normally you need to put your iPhone into recovery mode
>   when your want to do a firmware restore.

Once you put it in Recovery Mode, you see a popup on your computer screen saying "iTunes has detected an iPhone in recovery mode". From here, you should be able to restore.

[Windows Download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/xhlteg976vla8mz/RecBoot_v1.1_Win.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Hold the home button until the phone displays the "Connect to iTunes" icon.